# Crop point to remove points outside rectangle

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to remove point outside of rectangle from cloud, but I seem to can't get this right.
Also I try to implement extremes(), but could get this right either. I don't know where I did wrong.

For extremes(): returns null if the Cloud is empty, and an array of x and y coordinate doubles: leftmost, rightmost, top, bottom in that order otherwise. For example, if the cloud contains [ (0.0,0.0), (1.0,1.0), (2.0,0.0), (1.0,-1.0) ], the result array is [0.0, 2.0, 1.0, -1.0].

Here is code for extreme:

```
public double[] extremes(){
     if (isEmpty()){
        return null;
    }

    double left = 0;
    double right = 0;
    double top = 0;
    double bottom = 0;

    double [] extremes = new double[4];
    extremes[0] = left;
    extremes[1] = right;
    extremes[2] = top;
    extremes[3] = bottom;
    return extremes;
}
```

For Crop: crop has parameters that are two Points in the Cloud. One of these two points is a bottom corner, and the other a top corner, of a rectangle. The top corner is diagonally across from the bottom corner. Crop will remove all points outside this rectangle from the Cloud much like you would crop an image. The crop method must deal with two input points on a horizontal or vertical line segment, in which case all points not on the line segment are removed, and it must deal with two equal Points p1 and p2, in which case all Points but p1 (if is exists in the cloud) are removed from the Cloud.

For example, if the two input Points are (0.0,0,0) and (1.0,1.0), all Points outside the square delimited by (0.0,0.0), (0.0,1.0), (1.0,1.0), and (0.0,1.0) are removed, but if the two input Points are (0.0,0,0) and (0.0,1.0), all Points outside the line segment delimited by (0.0,0.0), and (0.0,1.0) are removed.

Here is code for crop:

```
public void crop(Point p1, Point p2){

        Point left = points.get(0);
        Point right = points.get(1);
        Point top = points.get(2);
        Point bottom = points.get(3);

        // check if in square
        if (left.getX() > p1.getX() || left.getX() < p1.getX() || 
                left.getY() > p1.getY() || left.getY() < p1.getY()){
            points.add(left);
        }else
            points.remove(left);
        if (right.getX() > p1.getX() || right.getX() < p1.getX() || 
                right.getY() > p1.getY() || right.getY() < p1.getY()){
            points.add(right);
        }else
            points.remove(right);
        if (top.getX() > p2.getX() || top.getX() < p2.getX() || 
                top.getY() > p2.getY() || top.getY() < p2.getY()){
            points.add(top);
        }else
            points.remove(top); 
        if (bottom.getX() > p2.getX() || bottom.getX() < p2.getX() || 
                bottom.getY() > p2.getY() || bottom.getY() < p2.getY()){
            points.add(bottom);
        }else
            points.remove(bottom);


        // check coordinate
        if(p1.getX() == left.getX() && p1.getY() < left.getY() && left.getY() < p2.getY() ||
                p1.getX()  < left.getX() && left.getX() < p2.getX() && p1.getY() == left.getY()){
            points.add(left);
        }

        if(p1.getX() == right.getX() && p1.getY() < right.getY() && right.getY() < p2.getY() ||
                p1.getX()  < right.getX() && right.getX() < p2.getX() && p1.getY() == right.getY()){
            points.add(right);
        }
        if(p1.getX() == top.getX() && p1.getY() < top.getY() && top.getY() < p2.getY() ||
                p1.getX()  < top.getX() && top.getX() < top.getX() && p1.getY() == top.getY()){
            points.add(top);
        }
        if(p1.getX() == bottom.getX() && p1.getY() < bottom.getY() && bottom.getY() < p2.getY() ||
                p1.getX()  < bottom.getX() && bottom.getX() < bottom.getX() && p1.getY() == bottom.getY()){
            points.add(bottom);
        }

        if(p1.getX() == p2.getX() || p1.getY() == p2.getY()){
            points.add(p2);
        }
}
```

Other code for this class:

```
private ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();;

public boolean isEmpty(){
return size() == 0;
}

public int size(){
return 0;
}

public boolean hasPoint(Point p){
return points.contains(p);
}

public void addPoint(Point p){  
// Don't do anything if p in list
    if(points.contains(p)){ 
    }else{
    points.add(p);
    }
}
```

Edited!

Comment: You could make use of the 2D Graphics Shapes API, which has a `Rectangle` class which provides a `contains` method to determine if a give `Point` falls within its bounds...

Comment: Your `extremes` method does not do anything else than allocating a new array a four zeros double. Plus, you are doing very weird tests in `crop`. For example, your first test is equivalent to `left.getX() != p1.getX() && left.getY() != p1.getY()`, which I doubt to be your intention.

Comment: Can you please explain exactly what both of your methods are supposed to do?